# Spring MVC 3, forwarding not working when using Ajax

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, spring, forward

I have very interesting problem. I am making log in page for my web app and I am sending login request via AJAX. If success I want to forward user to another page.

It seems that his is what happens. I send Ajax request, controller forwards me to need view (I see log in debug mode) but I stay on the same page, since I assume the page is waiting for AJAX response and for that reason forwarding does not happen.

I think this is also wrong way to approach this but since I am new to this don't know better. How can I log in and and forward user to next page.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

JS Code:

```
    Page.authenticate = function() {
        $.ajax({
              url: "/login/authenticate/" + $('#username').val() + "/" + $('#password').val(),
              type: "GET",
              success: function(poi){
                 // alert("nesto");
              }
           });

        return true;
    }
```

Controller Class:

```
@Controller
public class LoginPageController {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Autowired
private UserManagement userManagement; 

@RequestMapping(value="/login/authenticate/{username}/{password}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String authenticate(@PathVariable("username") String userName, @PathVariable("password") String password, Model model) {

if (userManagement.authenticateUser(userName, password)) {
        String forward = "forward:/login/success";
        return forward;
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid Username/Password, please try again!");
        return "/";
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You might want to check out Spring Security, which is a mature framework developed by SpringSource for authentication/authorization.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like good framework to secure your application. But still I will need this forwarding to work :)

Comment: If you use Spring Security, you won't need to deal with this issue as it will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to response within `@ResponseBody` Annotation if you are using AJAX.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/login/authenticate/{username}/{password}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String authenticate(@PathVariable("username") String userName, @PathVariable("password") String password, Model model) {

    if (userManagement.authenticateUser(userName, password)) {
            String forward = "forward:/login/success";
            return forward;
        } else {
            String forward = "forward:/login/error?message=Invalid Username/Password, please try again!";
            return forward;
        }

    }

     @RequestMapping(value="/login/success", method=RequestMethod.GET)
      @Responsebody
      public String handleMySuccessRedirect() {
         return "Logged In successfully"
              } 

 @RequestMapping(value="/login/error", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @Responsebody
  public String handleMyExceptionOnRedirect(@RequestParamter("message") String message) {
     return message;
          }
```

Update:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/login/authenticate/{username}/{password}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
    public String authenticate(@PathVariable("username") String userName, @PathVariable("password") String password, Model model) {

    if (userManagement.authenticateUser(userName, password)) {
            String response = "Logged Successfully";
            return response;
        } else {
            String response = "Invalid Username/Password, please try again!";
            return response;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you input, but this does not solve my problem. Since this forwards inside of same Controller.
I need to be forwarded on other Controller (other page).
I will keep in mind to use @ResponseBody annotation for AJAX calls.

Comment: Used full pledge response, and than forward works. One small problem is when you do POST and you forward request it goes as POST request. 
Since you cannot change method (maybe with reflection you can) forwarded request lands on the page as POST. Unfortunately I had to add handling for POST request and eventually got what I wanted. Not clean solution but its a start.

Comment: @Dolphin, Please see my update and use this suggestion. You don't need to redirect at all, BTW id I solved your problem please mark this question as accepted or increase its rating.

Comment: hi Danny both approaches are fine both they don't solve the problem. What I need is solution that allows me to go to other controller that is not current one. 

So lets say LogInController.java (view: \index.html) and if successful go to HomePageController.java (view: \home\main.html). 

So Cross controller forwarding, your solution is very good but it is forwarding inside of same controller.

Comment: I don't see any problem your are using ajax, if you got correct response redirect it in javascript by window.location.replace("\home\main.html");

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do here:

1. Don't return a view from your controller, instead return json, based on the response in json, set the location appropriately - `window.location = 'home.action'` - here is an [example using ext-js](http://loianegroner.com/2010/02/integrating-spring-security-with-extjs-login-page/)
2. Let the login page perform a full fledged post, not an AJAX post.

Comment: Thanks for help and I am looking into using full fledged post. As far as other solution that one is tied to using Spring Security which is overhead at the moment for me. All fails Spring Security here I come :)